# Is there a way to have a common section with buildConfigField and resValue in gradle?

Tags: android, gradle

I have a product with multiple product flavors like:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
    }

    release {
    }

}

productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        buildConfigField "String" "country" "se"
        buildConfigField "String" "language" "sv-SE"
        buildConfigField "String" "appName" "Flavor1"
    }
    flavor2 {
        buildConfigField "String" "country" "se"
        buildConfigField "String" "language" "sv-SE"
        buildConfigField "String" "appName" "Flavor2"
    }
    flavor3 {
        buildConfigField "String" "country" "se"
        buildConfigField "String" "language" "sv-SE"
        buildConfigField "String" "appName" "Flavor3"
    }
    flavor4 {
        buildConfigField "String" "country" "se"
        buildConfigField "String" "language" "sv-SE"
        buildConfigField "String" "appName" "Flavor4"
    }
    flavor5 {
        buildConfigField "String" "country" "se"
        buildConfigField "String" "language" "no-NO"
        buildConfigField "String" "appName" "Flavor5"
    }
}
```

I would prefer a common section with all properties and only override those that are different. Is this possible?

I would also like to put all flavors (and perhaps buildTypes) in it's own file to make it more readable. So whenever you have to change a flavor, you can easily find it in its own file, and not have to scroll over thousands of line which it will be if I have all flavors and buildTypes together with all the rest in the main build file.

Comment: I thought about that but it seems messy to add resValues and buildConfigFields to that section. But maybe it's the only way. What about moving it to a separate file?

Comment: `debug` and `release` of `buildTypes`  should do the trick too, but you have to put values to both ... anyway why it is messy? default config will contains default values ... about multiple files ... i never work with em

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear enough in my question. It becomes messy when you have 15 or more productFlavors and about 20 different keys. Then it would be nice to keep them from everything else around the build like signing, packaging, and all other information regarding the android sdk version and so on. That's why it becomes messy.

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Selvin is correct, use the `defaultConfig` closure - **there is no neater way!** In the following example, flavors 1, 2 & 5 would set the default country and language to `de`. Flavors 3 & 4 override this with their own languages.

```
defaultConfig {
    buildConfigField "String", "country", "de"
    buildConfigField "String", "language", "de"
}

buildTypes {
    debug {
    }

    release {
    }
}

productFlavors {
    flavor1 {
        buildConfigField "String", "appName", "Flavor1"
    }
    flavor2 {
        buildConfigField "String", "appName", "Flavor2"
    }
    flavor3 {
        buildConfigField "String", "country", "uk"
        buildConfigField "String", "language", "en_GB"
        buildConfigField "String", "appName", "Flavor3"
    }
    flavor4 {
        buildConfigField "String", "country", "fr"
        buildConfigField "String", "language", "fr"
        buildConfigField "String", "appName", "Flavor4"
    }
    flavor5 {
        buildConfigField "String", "appName", name.capitalize()
    }
}
```

**NOTE**

Just an FYI that you can use `name.capitalize()` to turn the name of any flavour, e.g. `flavor5`, into the app name of `Flavor5` by using the `capitalize()` method - which will capitalize the first character in the String. However, this **MUST** go in the flavor, not `defaultConfig`

Comment: Very helpful. Thank you very much !