# Creating template app for multiple android apps

Tags: android, android-library

So here is the thing. I want to create few apps, which they all should look exactly the same, but only one variable should change.
I'm looking for a way to create one library and to import it in all the other apps, and instead of updating a lot of apps, I would be able to update just the library.

Any ideas how such thing can be accomplished? Maybe using meta-data?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to [CommonsWear's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706775/creating-template-app-for-multiple-android-apps/27706879#27706879), which is correct *if* you are using Android Studio, what you require can also be achieved in Eclipse - albeit with a little more work.

You'd need to create a 'library application' (see image below) which should be your **base application** - i.e the app you want to be the common codebase of all the children-apps.

[image: Source: Vogella.com]

After that is completed and you should create a **new** Android project (a **child app**) that uses the base application library (see example image below)

[image: Source: Vogella.com]
<sub>(source: [vogella.com](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/images/xlibrary30.png.pagespeed.ic.C6oekZBznQ.png))</sub>

Any values in a **child app** (i.e. strings, styles, etc) are inherited from the parent **library app** `/res` folder unless you specify new values in the **child app** `/res` folder.

e.g. if `libraryapp/res/strings.xml` contains

`<string name="override_me">Hello</string>`

and `childapp/res/strings.xml` contains `<string name="override_me">Bonjour</string>`

then running the **child app** will return "Bonjour" rather than what was defined in the library.

As the child app is basically an empty project *without* activities, your child app's manifest should basically be a carbon copy of that of the library **apart** from the `<manifest>` tag which should contain the child app's `package`, `android:versionCode` and `android:versionName`. It can launch your library with these modified values like this:

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.library.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Being Eclipse, this *is* slightly more convoluted but if you manage to set up correctly, it makes creating **child apps** quick and easy (but just not as easy as with gradle!).

Comment: And what about the activities? How do I define them in the manifest?

Comment: @Erez.info see the changes to my answer. Basically you copy the manifest from the library project

Comment: thx man! it works great. I can even set different theme for each app without a problem :)

Comment: No worries, like I said this is not the easiest or best way to do it but it does work

Answer (score 1):

Create one app using Android Studio and Gradle for Android. Create multiple [product flavors](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors) for that app. [Use `buildConfigField`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25994149/is-there-a-way-to-have-a-common-section-with-buildconfigfield-and-resvalue-in-gr/26475964#26475964) to define the "variable" that changes based upon the flavor. When you build for your flavor, you get the app with the variable definition that you seek, along with anything else that you overrode in that product flavor (e.g., icon, `app_name`).

Comment: it looks exactly what I'm looking for, but I never worked with gradle so I will into that only as last option.