# Two Android applications sharing the same codebase. Switching Android Manifest?

Tags: java, android, android-manifest, apk

I have an existing android application and I am planning to create another one that would share the same functionality (same 3rd party libraries that I have already implemented into my first application) and even sharing the **same activities** (only started with different workflow).

I was wondering whether it is possible to build 2 APKs within one project simply by specifying multiple entry points (main activities)?

I presume that this is not possible. I such case I would probably have 2 AndroidManifest.xml files and switch them upon building the app.

Is there a better way to do this?

**Edit**:
I am using latest Android Studio with Gradle

Comment: Are you using android studio or eclipse? I think you could do much of this with the gradle build system of android studio and probably the build system within eclipse as well (I haven't used that though). I think its easier to modify the manifest rather than all out replace it. Manually changing manifests (and presumably package identifiers) without some sort of build system is a pain

Comment: [It can be done in Eclipse too](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27706775/creating-template-app-for-multiple-android-apps/27707160#27707160)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can achieve this with gradle's `productFlavors`. Each flavor can use custom java code or/and custom resources. [Read more](http://blog.robustastudio.com/mobile-development/android/building-multiple-editions-of-android-app-gradle/) about using flavors.

Comment: or if using android-maven|eclipse combination then use maven profiles to create two APK with there own resources.