# Android design/architecture: Create different Apps from same code base

Tags: android, architecture, mobile-application, application-design

I want to create two apps from same code base. They differ in color and some data coming from back end. Situation is like, Lets say I want to creat apps App1 and App2. Both have similar flow. Can I,

1. Select a Header color Blue if it is App1 and Red for other?
2. In code, if(running App == App1) { execute this part} else {other
   part}?
3. If App is App1 select layout1.xml for activity else select
   layout2.xml?

I am not sure how to go about this. Any help would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: i guess you need the Product Flavour Setup, provided in gradle build system in Android Studio. 
Links : https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio, what you are describing is product flavors. Quoting [the documentation](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Product-flavors):

> A product flavor defines a customized version of the application build by the project. A single project can have different flavors which change the generated application.

For the purposes of this answer, let's imagine that you have one project with two product flavors, `flavorOne` and `flavorTwo`. Your project would also have three sourcesets:

- `src/main/`, where most of your stuff goes
- `src/flavorOne/`, where stuff for one flavor goes
- `src/flavorTwo/`, where stuff for the other flavor goes

With that in mind...

> Select a Header color Blue if it is App1 and Red for other?

In `src/main/res/values/colors.xml`, define a color named `header`, and give it a blue value. In `src/flavorTwo/res/values/colors.xml`, define a color named `header`, and give it a red value. The rest of your app refers to the `header` color (e.g., `@color/header`, `R.color.header`). When you build `flavorOne`, the `main` color will be used. When you build `flavorTwo`, the `flavorTwo` value will override the `main` value.

> If App is App1 select layout1.xml for activity else select layout2.xml?

In `src/main/res/layout/thingy.xml`, define your default layout implementation. In `src/flavorTwo/res/layout/thingy.xml`, define the layout you want to use for `flavorTwo`. Your Java code would refer to `R.layout.thingy`. When you build `flavorOne`, the `main` layout will be used. When you build `flavorTwo`, the `flavorTwo` layout will override the `main` layout.

> In code, if(running App == App1) { execute this part} else {other part}?

This would depend a bit on how much code you have that varies.

If it is substantial, you can use the strategy pattern:

- Have one implementation of `StuffStrategy` in `src/flavorOne/java/`
- Have another implementation of `StuffStrategy` in `src/flavorTwo/java/`
- In your `src/main/java` code, refer to `StuffStrategy`, and it will pull in the right implementation based upon the flavor that you are building

If the code variation is really trivial, you could use `buildConfigField` to provide a value for some new field (e.g., `STUFF`) to be added to the `BuildConfig` class, where that value would vary by flavor. [This Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26475964/115145) shows the details.

Comment: As to upload these apps on Play Store, we need to have different packages, so can we upload these two flavors as two different application?

Comment: @Sagar: Sure. That's the entire point. Product flavors model your distribution strategy, where you want to distribute N different apps, which *logically* are all the same app with minor variations.

Comment: How would I select different layouts for apps on runtime?

Comment: @RohitShinde: I do not understand your question, sorry. You may wish to ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you can explain your concerns in detail.

Comment: @CommonsWare If I were to have 2 different flavours of apps, then they would have different activity layouts as well. So, do I specify in the Activity's onCreate method what layout I want to inflate? And if so, how do I know which flavour of the app am I running?

Comment: @RohitShinde: "then they would have different activity layouts as well" -- you could set it up that way, but that is not the default behavior. "do I specify in the Activity's onCreate method what layout I want to inflate?" -- no. You name the layout the same in each flavor's source set.

Answer (score 1):

If you are **not** using Android Studio, then I will mention about another possibility. For the main functionality you can create a Library project as the base of your two applications (Check it as library project, and include it as library to both of your separated projects) and then extend activities, classes that you want to end up with different behaviours.

For example (simple one), If you have two Applications with different splash layout, let's say `splash.xml`, you can create this default one in Library project, and create a different one in layout folder with the same name in other project's resource directory. Second project will use the one in it's own layout folder.

I would recommend Android Studio and Gradle with flavors, as in @CommonsWare's answer, but if you are not using it, you can make it this way as well.